# How to find perfect numbers upto 10^18 in C?

Tags: math, number-theory, perfect-numbers

I have a C code off finding large perfect numbers below,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    unsigned long long num,i,sum;

    while (scanf ("%llu",&num) != EOF && num)
    {
        sum = 1;

        for (i=2; i*i<=num; i++)
        {
            if (num % i == 0)
            {
                if (i*i == num)
                    sum += i;
                else
                    sum += (i + num/i);
            }
        }

        if (sum == num)
            printf ("Perfect\n");
        else if (sum > num)
            printf ("Abundant\n");
        else
            printf ("Deficient\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to find whether a number is perfect, abundant or deficient. I run a loop upto the square root of `num`to minimize the runtime. It works fine `<= 10^15` but for the larger values it takes too long time to execute.

For example,for the following input sets,

```
8
6
18
1000000
1000000000000000
0
```

this code shows the following outputs,

```
Deficient
Perfect
Abundant
Abundant
Abundant
```

But, for 10^16 it doesn't respond quickly.

So, is there any better way to find a perfect number for too long values? Or is there any better algorithm to implement here??? :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a better algorithm.

Your algorithm is basically the simple one--adding up the divisors of a number to find... the sum of the divisors of a number (excluding itself). But you can use the number-theoretic formula for finding the sum of the divisors of a number (including itself). If the prime numbers dividing `n` are `p1`, `p2`, ..., `pk` and the powers of those primes in the canonical decomposition of `n` are `a1`, `a2`, ..., `ak`, then the sum of the divisors of `n` is

```
(p1**(a1+1) - 1) / (p1 - 1) * (p2**(a2+1) - 1) / (p2 - 1) * ...
    * (pk**(ak+1) - 1) / (pk - 1)
```

You can find the prime divisors and their exponents more quickly than finding *all* the divisors of `n`. Subtract `n` from that expression above and you get the sum you want.

There are some tricks, of course, to find the `pi`s and `ai`s more efficiently: I'll leave that to you.

---

By the way, if your purpose is just to find the perfect numbers, as in your title, you would do better to use [Euclid's formula for even prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Even_perfect_numbers). Find the Mersenne prime numbers by examining all `2**p-1` for prime `p` to see if they are prime--there are shortcuts to doing this as well--then constructing a perfect number from that Mersenne prime. This would leave out any [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers), though. If you find any, let the mathematical community know--that would make you world famous.

Of course, the fastest way of all to find perfect numbers is to use [the lists already made](https://oeis.org/A000396) of some of them.

Comment: That helps. :) ... thanks for sharing your knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of factorization of numbers. You can read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

Unfortunately no good news for you - the bigger the number gets, the longer it takes.

To start with your code, try not to multiply `i*i` each iteration.
Instead of:
    for (i=2; i*i<=num; i++)

calculate square root of num first, and then compare
 `i <= square_root_of_num in the loop`.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Program to determine whether perfect or not

# include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

map<long long int, int> mp;    // to store prime factors and there frequency

void primeFactors(long long int n)
{
// counting the number of 2s that divide n
while (n%2 == 0)
{
    mp[2] = mp[2]+1;
    n = n/2;
}

long long int root = sqrt(n);
// n must be odd at this point.  So we can skip every even numbers next
for (long long int i = 3; i <= root; i = i+2)
{
    // While i divides n, count frequency of i prime factor and divide n
    while (n%i == 0)
    {
        mp[i] = mp[i]+1;
        n = n/i;
    }
}

// This condition is to handle the case whien n is a prime number
    // greater than 2
    if (n > 2)
    {
        mp[n] = mp[n]+1;
    }
}

long long int pow(long long int base, long long int exp)
{
    long long int result = 1;
    base = base;
    while (exp>0)
    {
        if (exp & 1)
            result = (result*base);
        exp >>= 1;
        base = (base*base);
    }
    return result;
}

int main ()
{
    long long num, p, a, sum;

    while (scanf ("%lld",&num) != EOF && num)
    {
        primeFactors(num);
        sum = 1;

        map<long long int, int> :: iterator i;
        for(i=mp.begin(); i!=mp.end(); i++)
        {
            p = i->first;
            a = i->second;
            sum = sum*((pow(p,a+1)-1)/(p-1));
        }

        if (sum == 2*num)
            printf ("Perfect\n");
        else if (sum > num)
            printf ("Abundant\n");
        else
            printf ("Deficient\n");

        mp.clear();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried this code with the perfect number 2305843008139952128 but it gave the wrong answer, despite the number being well within the range of `long long int`.  The problem seems to be this expression `sum = (sum*(pow(p,a+1)-1))/(p-1);` which works correctly when expressed `sum = sum * ((pow(p,a+1)-1) / (p-1));` i.e. the order of multiplications and divisions matters.  An alternate fix (or upgrade) is to use `unsigned long long int` throughout.